# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJCCLASS$_ALAssetsLibrary"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I'm new to this site, my name is Kevin Griffiths and work mostly in 3D, I'm building a game in Unity3D for the last year and everything seemed to be going ok, until I have to upgrade my software .. :( and thats why I'm here looking for some help please as I really dont know my way around `Xcode`, I've just upgraded to the above and now when I build I get these 2 errors from `Xcode` anyone know how to correct these please I'd really appreciate the help.

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJCCLASS$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libScreenRecorder.a(MP4RecorderProcessor.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error means that `ALAssetsLibrary` is not added to your project target

You can use [adding framework tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH17-SW1) from Apple Doc.